# Django query: Getting data over two relations

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views, foreign-keys

I already googled much and read this site https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/ several times but I still have problems to get the right data.

I extended the standard Django-User-Model with a MAC-Adress because I will need it later. I also have a relationship between the models like this:

One "Django-Standard-User" has ONE UserProfile

ONE "UserProfile"          has MANY CalData

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    mac = models.CharField(max_length=17, default='00:00:00:00:00:00')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class CalData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    date = models.DateField(default="1970-01-01")
    timestamp = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    entry_id= models.CharField(max_length=100, default="NoID")
```

Now from the view, after the User has logged in, i want to make a query like this:
"give me a Query (not Objects) of Caldata where user = "the username of the Standard-Django-User" and where Date = Today.

The second Question is:
Is it better to set the ForeignKey of Caldata to "UserProfile" like I did or is it better to set it to "User" (standard Django-Model).
My Goal is to say: One User has one unique MAC-Adress and many CalData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

```
CalData.objects.filter(user__user__username=request.user.username)
```

gives you the user with a username. The double-underscore notation is really powerful in Django, and lets you traverse tables. And if you have the correct middleware, every logged-in request should have a user field.

Second question: If a User doesn't have a UserProfile, do you want them to be able to associate with CalData? If so, link to User, and if not, to UserProfile.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Didnt know that you can traverse tables via double-underscore. If a User doesnt have a User-Profile he shall not be allowed to interact with CalData. So i guess it stays as it is :). Cant give you an upvote due to low score of mine :(